# How to work remotely for US companies as a foreigner

Tags: united-states, visa, remote-work

I am neither a US citizen nor have ever been in the US. I want to remotely work for US-based companies, and apparently, almost all companies require a visa or some sort of work permit even for remote jobs. I tried to apply for different kinds of documents, like I-765, but they either expect me to provide information about my employer from the US, or they take too long (about 6-8 months) to accept or decline my application. I feel so lost and I don't know what I should do now. I expected the bureaucratic side of remote work would be much easier to complete.

Comment: The bureaucratic side of working in a foreign country is a huge hurdle, remote work or not.

Comment: And maybe you should think about why you want to work for a US company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I applied to those companies, too. But they are only a few in number while there is a myriad of remote positions in the US. And, my field is data science/Python development if that helps, and I want to believe companies have an easy option for foreign workers.

Answer (score 3):

#### You need to work for a local subsidiary or contracting organization

For a company to hire you and pay you as a US employee, you need to be able to work in the US.  There is nothing then keeping you from then working overseas, other than the laws of the country you work in.  Notably, many nations will require you to pay taxes there if you are there over a certain amount of time, and companies whose employees do this usually have accounting firms do the employee's foreign taxes, including paying additonal taxes for the employee.  US tax treatment would be another thing entirely.

In general, it is too hard for a US company to employ you in a foreign country, because the US company doesn't know anything about your local labor laws.  This might lead the company to either create a subsidiary locally, or pay a company there to hire and pay you as a pass-through entity for your wages, similar to a contractor.  This arrangement is much more likely for an existing employee who wants to live overseas (my company has such an arrangement) than a new employee who lives overseas already.  You would need to have remarkable value for a company to go through all this just for you.

Comment: So, can't any foreigner outside the US remotely work for US-based companies, except for some instances? What I actually wonder is what 'work authorization' exactly is and how to get it as a foreigner. I am open to paying good prices if needed. And my aim at the moment is to work remotely, so I don't plan to reside in the US in the near future.

Comment: @remotework it's conceivably possible, but practically impossible.  Work Authorization is the I-9 process, and the Visa required for your citizenship.

Comment: “because the US country” - Did you mean to use the word “country”?

Comment: @remotework - “So, can't any foreigner outside the US remotely work for US-based companies, except for some instances?” - No; The potential employee must be authorized to work in the country or the company has a branch in the potential employees country. In other words you need a work visa or be employed locally be the company due to their presence in your country.  This is how Google hires developers in other countries.

Comment: It's also a possibility for the OP to set up their own consulting company in their home country and then offer their company's services to companies in the US. This is what I did for about 5 years before getting H1-B'ed over here (although I was operating the company in my home country for a number of years before beginning to sell my services in the US).

Answer (score 1):

Some companies offer work visas as part of their employment. If you're looking at jobs in the US, I'd recommend searching for jobs that offer visas. I've never used [myvisajobs.com](https://www.myvisajobs.com/Search_Visa_Sponsor.aspx) before, but it might be helpful. It has search functionality that will allow you to find employers who sponsor visas. For instance, they say google sponsored 30k visas in 2020, but it applied for visas at a very high rate (4th highest by number of applications). Twitter for comparison applied for 465 visas and was the 98th highest applying firm.

For a smaller company, they're almost certainly not going to go through the work of applying for a visa, so you have to find firms that have a track record of applying for and getting visas for prospective employees.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't plan to reside in the US in the near future, but I want to work completely remotely, and I wonder if there is an alternative way to show I'm 'authorized to work in the US' other than getting a visa.

Comment: @remotework - No; There isn’t.

Comment: @remotework If you don't have the right visa, you are not authorized to work in the US.